# Minecraft Server To Client protocol - 18 byte packet on login request

Tags: vb.net, protocols, minecraft

I'm working with the [Minecraft Server To Client protocol](http://mc.kev009.com/Protocol#Server_to_Client) documentation for a server I am making.

It says the packet is 18+ bytes, but I can't seem to figure out what each byte is for.

Comment: You are going to need to provide a lot more detail about your specific issue.  The page you linked to contains a fairly complete specification for the minecraft communications protocol.

Comment: I thought it a bit 'amateur' that the widths of each field were not listed (in addition to their type interpretation), it's a protocol reference after all. Anyone worth their salt would have written the tables proper. Once you get over that, terminology becomes horrible and misleading and types are misintepreted altogether. The spec is a good start, and it's crap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity ID = int = 4 bytes
Map Seed = long = 8 bytes 
Dimension = byte = 1 byte ?

strings are variables sizes, hence why it says "Total Size: 18 bytes + length of strings"

Sorry I can't be more specific, more detail is needed

Answer (score 0):

It also says that strings are a short (2 byte) length followed by the string.

Understanding what values go in each of those fields is a much more complicated issue, and i doubt anyone here can help with that.